# Why can I execute without read permissions?

Tags: bash

Why can I execute programs without reading them?

```
$ echo 'echo "foo"' > test && chmod 100 test && ./test
foo
```

Comment: Suppose you are an admin and you have users whom you want to be able to run a script. If those users have permissions to also change the script somehow, it's a security hole. Same with reading - if users can see how it's implemented , they can try to find ways to bypass it

Comment: But *who* is executing the script if the user is not able to read it?

Comment: The shell.  User gives commands to the shell.

Comment: @Brettetete:  I can reproduce this only as user root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your stated test command and case will only work under `root` (superuser), based on my tests with the exact same command on my Ubuntu Trusty box.

This is an unprivileged account:

```
[teward /home/teward/tmp/]% echo 'echo "foo"' > test && chmod 100 test && ./test
zsh: permission denied: ./test
```

This is as root:

```
[god /home/teward/tmp/]# echo 'echo "foo"' > test && chmod 100 test && ./test
foo
```

(Regarding `god` on my root prompt:  I have `root` and my user using `zsh` as the login shell.  My `PS1` for ZSH replaces 'root' with 'god' for the root user on my system, but it's still 'root'.  Privilege level is indicated by the character to the right of the closing square brace - the `#` indicates root, and `%` indicates standard user, which is how you know the privilege level)

I think this is because 'root' is considered god, and can do almost anything.  Double-check the user you're using.

Comment: Oh that's awkward. I haven't even thought about trying this as non-root. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Brettetete no offense but that's a _very_ good indication that you probably shouldn't be running as root.

Comment: @Brettetete I have to agree with terdon here - if you haven't thought about working with your computer as an **unpriviliged, non-root user**, then you should probably start doing this now...

Answer (score 1):

Because your shell has to read the file to know what to execute. If you remove read access, it can't read it so doesn't know what you want executed.

Comment: Not quite correct. You can have file without read-write permissions, but have permission to execute it.

Comment: The shell has to be able to read the file to execute it. If you remove read permission for all users, the shell cannot read the file and therefore cannot execute it. Try it!

Comment: @Serg That only holds true to the `root` account as permissions don't matter to it.  As a normal user, it cannot be read, so executing a file as a normal user it should say permission denied.